# Unable to access global variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables

I am trying to access a var one file from another file. Here is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button id="btn">Global</button>
    <script src="/test.js"></script>
    <script src="/testpass.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
export var globalVariable = {
    output: "test this"
 };
```

testpass.js:

```
import { globalVariable } from './test.js'
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert(globalVariable.output);
});
```

Nothing happens. I also tried doing

```
var globalVariable = {
    output: "test this"
 };
```

and then simply accessing it from another file as demonstrated in this answer:
[Call variables from one javascript file to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351265/call-variables-from-one-javascript-file-to-another) but it did not work. Tried exporting it as mentioned in this answer: [Can I access variables from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244361/can-i-access-variables-from-another-file) as well but no success. I am using sublime text and vue.js and it does not work for both of them.

In addition if I do something like this:

```
import { globalVariable } from '.test.js'
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert("Not printing the globalVariable here");
});
```

the entire javascript file seems to fail and doesn't work at all when called in the HTML file.

Comment: "Nothing happens" means that not even the alert window appears?

Comment: Don't use es6 modules much myself, but I seem to recall that you need a `type=module` on the script tag for it to be treated as a module

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39944861/should-i-reference-files-in-a-script-tag-when-using-es6-modules-in-a-browser

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be getting an error from the browser's JavaScript engine in the web console. To use `import` and `export`, you have to treat your code as a *module*. Your `script` tags don't, they treat the code as just *script*. To treat `testpass.js` as a module, you must use `type="module"`:

```
<script src="/testpass.js" type="module"></script>
```

No need to list `test.js`, `testpass.js` will load it. So:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="btn">Global</button>
    <script src="/testpass.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sadly, we can't show modules in SO's Stack Snippets, but if you make those changes, [this codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wqw1xppklw) is what you end up with (except I changed `src="/testpass.js"` to `src="./testpass.js"`).

---

Note that `globalVariable` **isn't** a global variable (which is a Good Thing™). It's a local variable within `test.js` that it exports. Any other module can import it, but it's not a global.